# Getting the data of nested collections in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am making my first angular/Firestore app and I am having some trouble understanding how to retrieve data in nested collections. My Firestore dB path I want to read from is here:

```
/Customer(CollectionName)/cl0Apvalb6c0w9hltQ8AOTF4go23(userUIDby)/Order(subcollectionName)/7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2(auto-id)
```

So Customer is a collectionName, `cl0Apvalb6c0w9hltQ8AOTF4go23(USERUID)` is a USER-UID for a user. Authentication, Order another collectionName, and `7WqHl5YUKPszkRELXEI2` is an auto-id for an added order.

In this each user can **GET** its own data but as **Admin** I want to get to see all user data.

I want All FIRESTORE data of users to display on angular as I am making an admin panel in angular 12.

```
export class OrderlistsService {

    itemsCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;

    items!: Observable<Item[]>;

    itemDoc!: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;

    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

    getOrdersItems() {
       return this.firestore.collection<Item>('customer').valueChanges();
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load the orders from all users, you're looking for a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). In [AngularFire](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) that'd be:

```
this.firestore.collectionGroup<Item>('Order').valueChanges();
```

This reads the documents from all subcollections named `Order`, no matter where they exist in your database.